# SQLAlchemy: Does every table in the database have to relate to a class in the application?

Tags: python, oop, orm, sqlalchemy

I have an application that I want to implement in Python 3.2 and SqlAlchemy 0.8. Am done with the ERD and it has about 30 tables as of now. Question is, now that I have 30 Postgresql tables, Does this mean that in my SQLAlchemy ORM implementation I'll have to create the 30 classes? This comes from the fact that so far in my application, I've created about 8 tables and for each of this tables I've had to create the classes.

In my ERD, a number of the tables are "pivot" tables e.g. a table called **organizaton_type** that has only 2 columns (ID & Name columns). Only a maximum of 3 entries will be in this table i.e."Public, Private, Partnership". This **organization_type** table relates to the **organization** table.

While in my database knowledge of normalization I think this is an okay design, I feel a bit hesitant to create a class called Organization Type. Is there a way I can still access those "pivot" tables without creating their equivalent classes and without having to write my own raw SQL queries?

Maybe to drive my confusion home, is it that in OO Development and while using ORMs I don't have a choice but to implement those classes in order to access the tables?

Comment: Well. If you're using an object relational mapper then you should have an object reflecting an entity if you intend to use it in the object relational mapper. If you're concerned about the amount of code needed to reconcile your object model with your already implemented database schema then you might want to look at sqlalchemy's reflection capabilities: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#reflecting-database-objects

Comment: I have a longer answer here based on the fact that you can use recipes like those in http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/05/17/magic-a-new-orm/ to automate tasks that seem redundant, including automating the creation of new mapped classes, but also keep in mind if you really don't want to have any boilerplate at all you can use a tool like [SQLSoup](https://sqlsoup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (which also creates mapped classes for new table names as needed).  The advantage to mapping them is that you can work with relationship() effectively.